# Does the Darkmoon Blade Covenant Ring work from anywhere?

Tags: dark-souls

In Dark Souls, does the **Darkmoon Blade Covenant Ring** work from any PVP location? I've been wearing it for quite a while, but it only worked a few times while I was at Anor Londo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Darkmoon Blade covenant ring can summon you from outside of Anor Lando but cannot summon you from 'anywhere'. It can only summon your while you are in another 'pvp/coop' area.  (any area where you can put down your white soap stone or use the blue orb)

Example: It can summon you while you are in New Londo Ruin, but not while you are at the Firelink Shrine.